# Виртуальное окружение Django

Tags: python, django

При создании виртуального окружения Django на  Windows 10 x64 не создается файл manage.py
Поэтапно создаю:

```
python -m venv log_env

log_env\Scripts\activate

pip install Django

django-admin.py startproject log
```

В каталоге должен создаваться фаил manage.py но его нет.
При попытке запустить сервер командой `python manage.py runserver` вылетает ошибка

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\log\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

что ожидаемо, т.к файл в каталоге отсутствует.
Как можно исправить и что делаю не так?

Comment: а в папку `log` вы перешли перед запуском?

Comment: У меня файл создаётся... У вас команда startproject точно никаких ошибок не выводит?

Answer (score 1):

1. убедись что находишься в каталоге проекта, чтобы запускать сервер
2. команда django-admin startproject log